# $(document).ready(function() {}) is being run before the Flex app loads in my page

Tags: jquery, apache-flex, flex4

I have a page with an some normal javascript, a swf file and some jquery.

I'm running my jquery code inside the $(document).ready(function() {}) function. But the code is being run before the Flex component (the swf file) has finished loading. Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of the "ready" event is to run *before* elements like images and Flash load. If you don't like that, use the "load" event instead.

```
$(document).load(function() { ... });
```

Another approach would be to try and attach a "load" handler to your flex object directly, but I'm not personally sure that'd work properly, and it might be a race condition for the "ready" handler to get the "load" handler set before the content actually does load.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event instead.

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.